# SQL Group By Day Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table `OutletVisit` which have a column `DTOEntry` which is in DateTime format.

Table Structure

```
DTOEntry  |  OutletID 
18-01-2016|     1     
18-01-2016|     2    
18-01-2016|     3     
18-01-2016|     4     
27-01-2016|     1     
27-01-2016|     2    
27-01-2016|     3     
29-01-2016|     4
```

Now what output do I desire is basically `group by` From `Thursday`[Inclusive] to `Wednesday`

```
From      |  To        |  OutletID |  ActualDate 
14-01-2016| 20-01-2016 |   1       |  18-01-2016
14-01-2016| 20-01-2016 |   2       |  18-01-2016
14-01-2016| 20-01-2016 |   3       |  18-01-2016
14-01-2016| 20-01-2016 |   4       |  18-01-2016
21-01-2016| 27-01-2016 |   1       |  27-01-2016
21-01-2016| 27-01-2016 |   2       |  27-01-2016
21-01-2016| 27-01-2016 |   3       |  27-01-2016
28-01-2016| 03-02-2016 |   4       |  29-01-2016
```

How to write a dynamic `SQL` for this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: why does it need to be dynamic sql?

Comment: Do you have a time table that includes all dates? or a table that include the FROM and TO dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear why you want "dynamic sql", but you can calculate the week starting each Thursday using date functions.

- datediff(day,fromdate,todate) returns the number of days as an
  integer
- datediff(day,-4,DTOEntry) is the number of days from a Thursday in Dec 1899
- divide that number by 7 (nb. this is an integer result)
- multiply that number by 7
- add that number to -4 to arrive at the date for the week starting a Thursday

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/94e3e/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE OutletVisit 
    ([DTOEntry] datetime, [OutletID] int)
;

INSERT INTO OutletVisit 
    ([DTOEntry], [OutletID])
VALUES
    ('2016-01-18 00:00:00', 1),
    ('2016-01-18 00:00:00', 2),
    ('2016-01-18 00:00:00', 3),
    ('2016-01-18 00:00:00', 4),
    ('2016-01-27 00:00:00', 1),
    ('2016-01-27 00:00:00', 2),
    ('2016-01-27 00:00:00', 3),
    ('2016-01-29 00:00:00', 4)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
      ca.weekstart
    , DATEADD(DAY, 6, ca.weekstart) AS weekfinish
    , ov.*
FROM OutletVisit ov
      CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT
                  DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, -4, DTOEntry) / 7) * 7, -4) AS weekstart
      ) AS ca
```

An alternative that could be used, using a "derived table" (or "subquery"):

```
SELECT
      weekstart
    , DATEADD(DAY, 6, weekstart) AS weekfinish
    , DTOEntry
    , OutletID
FROM (
      SELECT
            DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, -4, DTOEntry) / 7) * 7, -4) AS weekstart
          , ov.DTOEntry
          , ov.OutletID
      FROM OutletVisit ov
      ) AS derived
;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/94e3e/1/0)**:

```
|                 weekstart |                 weekfinish |                  DTOEntry | OutletID |
|---------------------------|----------------------------|---------------------------|----------|
| January, 14 2016 00:00:00 |  January, 20 2016 00:00:00 | January, 18 2016 00:00:00 |        1 |
| January, 14 2016 00:00:00 |  January, 20 2016 00:00:00 | January, 18 2016 00:00:00 |        2 |
| January, 14 2016 00:00:00 |  January, 20 2016 00:00:00 | January, 18 2016 00:00:00 |        3 |
| January, 14 2016 00:00:00 |  January, 20 2016 00:00:00 | January, 18 2016 00:00:00 |        4 |
| January, 21 2016 00:00:00 |  January, 27 2016 00:00:00 | January, 27 2016 00:00:00 |        1 |
| January, 21 2016 00:00:00 |  January, 27 2016 00:00:00 | January, 27 2016 00:00:00 |        2 |
| January, 21 2016 00:00:00 |  January, 27 2016 00:00:00 | January, 27 2016 00:00:00 |        3 |
| January, 28 2016 00:00:00 | February, 03 2016 00:00:00 | January, 29 2016 00:00:00 |        4 |
```

Note to control the display of datetime values at output use FORMAT() or CONVERT(). Sqlfiddle's display defaults have been used in the result above.

Please also note that really a week starts at (say) January, 14 2016 00:00:00 and finishes at January, 21 2016 00:00:00, a duration of 7 days. The column "weekfinishes" uses a duration of 6 days to match your expected result.

Comment: Do we really need `Cross Apply` here. This may confuse new comer's.  A `sub-select` or `CTE` will also be more readable and easy to understand

Comment: Do we need it? No. But it is effective for this and there are alternatives (as you have mentioned). However I do not believe a CTE would improve legibility at all, quite the reverse. A simple derived table can be used in lieu - I will add one.